# Design a MongoDB schema for items inside few lists

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and I want to design schema for eCommerce Website.
I only ask about one example and I hope it will help me for the whole design.

Requirements:

- Item contains at least name and price.
- Cart is list of items the user select.
- Wishlist is list of items the user select.
- If the admin edit an item it should effect the Cart and Wishlist.

I consider some options:

1. Array of items id in Cart and Wishlist.
2. Cart with embedded items and Wishlist with embedded items.

What are the pros and cons? 
Is there another way to design this?

Any example will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: So, as far as I can tell, you'd want something like this: `User: { cart: [{itemID : someID, price: price}], WishList: [{itemID : someID}]` - for the User document, and the Item document would have it's collection of items. You then store Item *references* inside the User document.

Comment: @tymeJV In this case, what happened when the price of item changed?

Comment: If the Item price is changed, you change that in the Item document, the User document will only store references. I only included `price` as an example (and clearly a bad one), `Maker` might be a better choice. The point was, you store references to other documents like that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//item
{
    _id : Number,
    name : String,
    price : Number
}
//user
{
    _id : Number,
    name : String,
    profile : {
        location : String,
        age : Number,
        created_at : Date,
        /*something something something*/
    },
    wishlist : {
        item_id : [Number] // store item's _ids
    }
}
```

I don't think using Database to store the cart data is common way.
usually you can use session/get/post/cookie instead